# Passing a HTML array to PHP through jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm stuck in a probably very common problem when working with HTML forms and jQuery AJAX, but I have not found a proper solution that fits my specific needs yet... I am using Codeigniter Framework.
Here is the specific situation:

HTML - A form with an array, address[], like:

```
<form id="addressForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">    
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <label class="control-label" for="address[name]">Full name</label>
        <input name="address[name]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label class="control-label" for="address[email]">Email</label>
       <input name="address[email]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>
... and so on
```

jQuery - AJAX call passing two parameters to PHP: an ID and the address array serialized...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "ajax/updateClientAddress",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
    id: $('select[name="addresses"]').val(),
        address: $("[name^='address[']").serialize(),
    }
...
```

PHP - Data processing and client update

```
...
 $addressID = $this -> input -> post('id');   // Correctly received
 $addressData = $this -> input -> post('address');
...
```

I would like to know what is missing or wrong in each part to access the data in PHP like this:

```
$client -> name = $addressData['name'];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add the id name/value pair to the address param string and pass that finished param string as the data.

```
data: $.param({id: $('select[name="addresses"]').val()}) + "&" + $("[name^='address[']").serialize(),
```